# In momentum theory, what happens if atmospheric velocity is larger than outflow velocity?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, momentum, aerodynamics

I am currently reading up on aerodynamics, essentially the actuator disk concept and momentum theory as it is described in e.g. *Basic Helicopter Aerodynamics* by Seddon and Newman.

There they assume the air to be an incompressible fluid and express the thrust force $T$ as a function of density, rotor disk area $A$, inflow velocity $v_i$ and downstream infinity (i.e. final outflow) velocity $v_\infty$ as

\begin{align}
T = \rho A v_i v_\infty
\end{align}

which I assume is the simplified static thrust form of

\begin{align}
T = \rho A v_i (v_\infty - v_{self})
\end{align}

where $v_{self}$ is either the atmospheric velocity if the engine itself is static or the engine velocity if the atmospheric velocity is zero. (At least this seems to be coherent with what I found in Durands *Aerodynamic Theory*, although I am generally missing where the $v_i \cdot v_\infty$ comes from, conceptually.)

I was now wondering how to interpret this, as I can see three different outcomes here:

1. $\vec{v}_\infty = \vec{v}_{self}$; if the outflow velocity is the same as in the environment, then there is no energy transported to the outflow and thus no force applied, so $\vec{T} = 0$,
2. $\vec{v}_\infty > \vec{v}_{self}$; if the outflow is faster than the environment, then there is a positive force $\vec{T}$ applied to the outflow, which in turn accounts for a positve thrust (of $-\vec{T}$, presumably) and
3. $\vec{v}_\infty < \vec{v}_{self}$, when the environment has a higher velocity than the outflow.

Now point 3. makes me wonder: Since now $T$ would be negative, that would also mean that $\vec{T}$ would point towards the inflow, which makes $-\vec{T}$ (the thrust) point towards the outflow, which in turn should slow down the system.

Is that correct? It seems strange to assume that a "slow" propeller engine (ignoring the area $A$ here for the sake of the argument) creates a backwards thrust. And how does the concept of drag fit in there?